# How display a csv file with a checkbox list on the right with Tkinter?

Tags: csv, tkinter, checkboxlist

I have been developing a program that loads a CSV file with "name" and "survived" columns filled with string and boolean values respectively. After loading the CSV file, the GUI will display
it as a table with names and a column of checked and unchecked checkboxes based on the values in the "survived" column. I can’t display the dataframe as an usable table where the user can change the values in the survived column by ticking the checkboxes. On top of that, I was asked to add a save function so that the use does not have to complete the task at one time.

Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import messagebox

titanic = pd.read_csv('titanic_small.csv').head(5)

names = titanic['name'].tolist()
life_states = titanic['survived'].tolist()

class LabeledCheckbutton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, check_var, func):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self, variable=check_var, command=func)
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)


root = Tk()
root.title('Checkbox List')
root.geometry("500x500")

#agreement = StringVar()

def checkbox_changed():
    pass



def checkboxClicked():
    print('Checkbox checked')
    result = check.get()
    print(result)
    # if checkbox_var.get():
    #     print('Checkbox checked')
    #     print(name, life_state)



for index, (name, life_state) in enumerate(zip(names, life_states)):

    #print(f'name: {name} life_state: {life_state}')
    if life_state is True:
        check = IntVar()
        checkbox = LabeledCheckbutton(check_var=check, func=checkboxClicked)
        checkbox.label.configure(text=name)
        checkbox
        checkbox.grid(row=index, column=0)
    else:
        check = IntVar()
        check = 0
        checkbox = LabeledCheckbutton(check_var=check, func=checkboxClicked)
        checkbox.label.configure(text=name)
        checkbox
        checkbox.grid(row=index, column=0)

    save_button = Button(root,'Quick Save')
    save_button.grid(row=len(titanic) + 1)


root.mainloop()
```

Here is the data the program loads.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WMv44p6GnTdFBxGQufd9Uc1beubXYgrL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *"I am having trouble displaying the CSV file"* It is not clear what the trouble is actually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hey my solution can still be improved, but if you make the `name` and `life state` attributes of your class, then every person is an `object` of this class and the attributes can be directly accessed and changed.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import messagebox

# attention, I used a semicolon as seperator
titanic = pd.read_csv('titanic_small.csv', sep=';').head(5)

names = titanic['name'].tolist()
life_states = titanic['survived'].tolist()

class LabeledCheckbutton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, var):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.check_var = IntVar(value=var)
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self, variable=self.check_var, command=self.checkboxClicked)
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.name = name
        self.life_state = life_state
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def checkboxClicked(self):
        print('Checkbox checked')
        # overwrite with the new variable, print the NEW life state of the person
        if self.check_var.get() == 0:
            self.life_state == False
        elif self.check_var.get() == 1:
            self.life_state == True
        print(f'name: {self.name} life_state: {self.check_var.get()}')


root = Tk()
root.title('Checkbox List')
root.geometry("500x500")


def checkbox_changed():
    pass


for index, (name, life_state) in enumerate(zip(names, life_states)):

    if life_state is True:
        checkbox = LabeledCheckbutton(var=1)
        checkbox.name = name
        checkbox.life_state = life_state
        checkbox.label.configure(text=name)
        checkbox.grid(row=index, column=0)
    else:
        checkbox = LabeledCheckbutton(var=0)
        checkbox.label.configure(text=name)
        checkbox.grid(row=index, column=0)

    save_button = Button(root, text='Quick Save')
    save_button.grid(row=len(titanic) + 1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I apologize for not replying to you sooner. I will try to implement the code and see if I can make it work with a large amount of data.